Problems while using QGIS Volume Calculator
The DEM and the polygon are in the same coordinate system but I am still getting 0 prices for V_above and V_below.
Is anyone having similar issues?


Which CRS are the layers in? Did you change the CRS of one of them?

They all are in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 same as the project CRS. Should I reproject them to another?
The project I am working on is in Greece.

Since your raster layers are in EPSG 4326 your default step size (X and Y at the bottom) in the tool is in degree - depending on your distance from the equator something up to 110 km.
Transform your data to a local m-based CRS, e.g. an UTM-zone (please not the world wide webmercator 3857) - otherwise the tool wont return m³.
